# Can Windows 10 Notifications be read aloud?

Tags: notifications, narrator

I'm looking to have Win 10 notifications read aloud as they arrive in. I've looked at Windows own Narrator as an option but can't seem to automate the process. I'm considering some form of macro / scripting tool but before i look, is there an option to do it within Windows itself?
Any help would be appreciated,